# Could not find 'nvcuda.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environmen

Tags: tensorflow

I have already set

```
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = ''
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
```

before importing any Tensorflow class. 
Why am I still getting this error? ( I don't have a GPU)

Comment: If you don't have a GPU you should not be using tensorflow-gpu   You should be using the non-GPU build of tensorflow.  You have installed the wrong tensorflow.  You may need to remove any tensorflow-gpu that you have installed, and re-install the non-GPU version of tensorflow.